# Long chapter title in thesis

Tags: latex

I am writing a thesis in latex, one of the chapters has quite a long title which I cannot rephrase or reduce. So, in the thesis, it extends the text width. How can I fix it, can the title be extended over multiple lines?

```
    \documentclass[a4paper,12pt, upper,crosshair,sfbold,chapterbib]{thesis}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \chapter{The title of the chapter: long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long}
    \lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you either share you thesis.cls or make a [mre] that does not reply on files we don't have access to?

Comment: My answer deals with adjusting the title of the chapter **in the page header**, as in your image. Please comment if something is not clear or doesn't fit :)

Comment: I have added the codes which may be used as minimal reproducible example. When these codes are run in Latex, I get the chapter title exceeding the text width in header. Please reply if these codes don't work.

Comment: @rgt The code does not help at all if you don't show us your class!

Answer (score 4):

Use the `\chaptermark` command to shorten the text area and linebreaks will be added automatically.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt, upper,crosshair,sfbold,chapterbib]{thesis}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \chapter{The title of the chapter: long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long}
    \chaptermark{\protect\parbox{0.9\linewidth}{The title of the chapter: long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long}}
    \lipsum
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Not sure about the documentclass `thesis`, but try this syntax:

```latex
\chapter[Short title for table of contents]{Long long long long long long long title}
\chaptermark{Short title for header}
```

No way to decently split the header over two lines: one suggestion is to use

```latex
\chapter{Long long long long long long long title}
\chaptermark{Long long...}
```

One thing would be to *resume* or *rephrase* the title, here the concept is to *truncate* it instead, rather than breaking it in two lines. This is not pleasant, but it happens some times.

Answer (score -1):

Use the line break operator `\\`.

Source: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56222/how-to-make-a-title-of-two-or-more-lines/56224

Comment: It does split the title in the main page, but I want to fit the title in text width as I highlighted in my question.  Above codes don't do that.